Validate a single boolean value using pydantic
I am using Pydantic extensively in my repository.
Pydantic is good at validating models. However, there are some cases where I might want to validate a single value, in this case a boolean. There are two examples:

I want to use a "before" validator, which runs before Pydantic's internal parsing and validation (such as converting from string to bool), but I want to use a boolean value in my model which Pydantic has not validated yet. Other values in my model depend on this boolean. In this case, I am forced to validate the boolean manually.
I want to parse command line arguments. Using type=bool with ArgumentParser would be a bad idea because the only falsy value it knows is an empty string (as mentioned in https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type). It would be nice to use Pydantic for this, for consistent behavior and because why reinvent the wheel when I already have Pydantic in my repository?

The two solutions I could come up with are:
Option 1. Make a dummy model that only has a single boolean
class _BoolWrapper(BaseModel):
    value: bool

def parse_bool(value: any) -> bool:
    return _BoolWrapper.model_validate(dict(value=value)).value

This works but it feels hacky to make a wrapper model with only one value when all I want is to validate a single boolean.
Option 2. Use a function from Pydantic v1
from pydantic.v1.validators import bool_validator

print(bool_validator('on'))  # True
print(bool_validator('off'))  # False
print(bool_validator(0))  # False
print(bool_validator(1))  # True
print(bool_validator('true'))  # True
print(bool_validator('false'))  # False

This works. But I don't know if using this function from an old version risks becoming deprecated or removed... And from what I could gather this is meant to be used as part of a decorator and not standalone?
Question
Is there a better way that I could not find or think of?
